# MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741571

Tags: c++

When I try to rebuild the [libarchive project](http://www.libarchive.org/) as requested [here](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/BuildInstructions#windowsvisual-studio). I get the following error :

> MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741571.

[image]

Any brilliant suggestion, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try compiling with the MinGW instructions? My feeling is MSVC is overflowing its internal shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First result from Google: http://www.febooti.com/products/automation-workshop/online-help/events/run-dos-cmd-command/exit-codes/

> Stack overflow / exhaustion. Error can indicate a bug in the executed
>   software that causes stack overflow, leading to abnormal termination
>   of the software.

Comment: what have you written please in Google to get this?

Comment: Thank you so much, but how do I to fix this please. I'll update my post, putting a picture discribing more the situation.

Comment: Create an other post for fixing the stack overflow problem, with your code. The most common error is to declare a huge array on the stack.

Comment: But it's not my code. The project is the result of `CMake` when I've applied it on the `libarchive` following the linked steps of installation.