# Error building libarchive for c++ Visual Studio 2010 Professional

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, libarchive

I am trying to build libarchive for c++ Visual Studio 2010 Professional.  Everything seems to be fine, the tests run OK, up until I get the following error:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741571.

Build FAILED.

I have googled and searched for this exact error on SO but cannot find anything.

Thank you.

Comment: Wild guess, maybe a post-build event which fails? Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547403/msb6006-cmd-exe-exited-with-code-1073741571

Comment: So how would I track that down?  I know very little about this, mostly I write code.

Comment: Open the project file (vcproj) ina text editor. Usually it just contains compiler/linker options and the source file list. If there are any special build events you should easily see them